# Estimate size of SQLite Database for offline dictionary

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to build offline Vocabulary builder app in android which has nearly 5000 words with each word having multiple fields(like synonyms,antonyms,related words etc..,)all these are placed into one table in a sqlite db and there is another table in which user can insert/delete words in it,at the maximum each word can be inserted into 15 rows in this second table.So max rows in this table can be 15x5000 =75,000.can anyone with experience in using sqlite db, estimate size of this db?.any comment on performance is also helpful.

Comment: `all these are placed into one table` Please, learn about **normalization**. Performances will be greatly increased by using **indexes** and **transactions**. As per the size... I really can't tell. Bus for sure **not less than a 2 MB** (but I'm expecting it to be bigger than this).

Comment: I did that in two tables because,if user resets the app or clears data, table 1 should be retained.

Comment: You should use **MORE than 1 table**. for the data (you should understand what the **R** in **RDBMS** really means). You can always provide a backup and restore facility to recover the old table.

Comment: thanks bob i know what R means,my primary key is word_id.and there is no  same data in two tables except that word_id.I only wish I can use 15 columns for each word rather than 15 rows,but there is no DROP COLUMN in sqlite.I have seen some solutions for that by creating temp table and copying all data.I wanted to trade off between that solution and this implementation.

Comment: You can save and reload your table to and from a CSV file. It's always desirable to have a row with AS LITTLE columns as possible. Use more tables and relate them. This will also optimize the database size, since (for instance) a word can be synonym of more than one only word.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two tables, you should write a textfile with sql commands for entering all the rows. And export this file inside your apk.

When your app is opened for the first time, execute the commands from this file by parsing the commands from it. Then everytime your application is opened just check for the count of rows in your DB. If it is 0 or any error occurs. Repeat the the above process. This way you don't have to keep two tables. Even if the user clears app memory, or resets it.

Download such a file from [here](http://www.mso.anu.edu.au/~ralph/OPTED/)(size of files is shown there). All you have to do is execute the "insert into.." commands like i described.

P.S : I know this should be in comments but i don't have enough reputation.